# Await Task outside of using statement

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have code:

```
Task<string> pageIdTask;
using (var seedSession = this.dbSessionManager.Start(agencyId))
{
    pageIdTask = seedSession.Query<ModelInfo>()
                .Where(mi=> mi.Id == modelId)
                .Select(mi=> mi.Tag)
                .SingleAsync();
}

var tokenTask = this.tokenManager.GetAsync(agencyId);

await Task.WhenAll(pageIdTask, tokenTask);

string pageId = pageIdTask.Result;
var token = tokenTask.Result;
```

Is it correct? I mean is it ok to await Task if it was initialized in using statement?

Or better to await Task in using statement?

Comment: Assuming that `seedSession` is running something like Entity Framework or whatever internally, you're going to dispose of it before you get to run the task, that's going to end badly for you :)

Comment: @DavidG, well yes, you are correct... I've tested it only in unit test, but seedSession was mocked... so yes. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no technical limitation in awating a task created in the scope of a using() statement outside of it, but in most cases that means the task's logic depends on whatever was inside the using() which is now disposed.
So in general something like this is ok:

```
Task task;
using(var something = GetSomething()){
    task = otherThing.CompletelyUnrelatedLogic();
}
task.Wait(); // no prob
```

But in most actual cases will be like:

```
Task task;
using(var something = GetSomething()){
    task = something.TaskThatWillFailAndExplodeIfExecutedWhenSomethingIsDisplosed();
}
task.Wait(); // BOOM
```